# Google Cloud Function: Dependency not found

Tags: vue.js, npm, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I am developing a project on Nuxt that I am deploying as a Google Cloud Function. (I Chose this as I am using a Cloud Firestore for my data storage)

It all works very nicely so far (Except the cold start time is persistently high - about 6 seconds but I think that is a separate matter). However, I keep getting this WARN in the logs on my Cloud Function:

> textPayload: " WARN  The dependency eslint not found. Please run yarn add eslint --dev or npm install eslint --save-dev"

There is nothing in the error to suggest where it is requiring eslint or why. This does not happen when I run my code or deploy locally.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.9.7",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^1.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.10.3",
    "cookieparser": "^0.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.13.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.12.2",
    "nuxt-client-init-module": "^0.1.8",
    "nuxt-start": "^2.11.0",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.0",
    "selectiveSSR": "file:./local-modules/selective-ssr",
    "shortid": "^2.2.15",
    "sortablejs": "^1.10.2",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "private": true
}
```

The Warning suggests it is looking for a dev-dependency. Surely I don't need these in my package.json? (Even if I add it in I still see the warning). There are references to the eslint package in my package-lock.json (which makes sense as I guess the nuxtjs/eslint packages in my package.json need it) but:

1. The link to the gzipped eslint NPM in package-lock.json works OK when I access it in my browser
2. Should Google not be using its Package Cache anyway to speed up the cold start? Is the issue that the specific version of eslint package-lock.json refers to is not available in Google's local package cache?

And yes I have tried adding eslint to my dependencies and devDependencies and it makes no difference.

Comment: A few things: 1) Please limit yourself to a single question per post on Stack Overflow - we need one, clear mission statement to address at a time. 2) Please show the minimal function code that exhibits this error. 3) Be absolutely clear what you're doing that causes the message to appear, and what is not working the way you expect - we should be able to reproduce the issue with your instructions.

Comment: 1) I can reduce the scope of the question.

2) This does not happen locally, only when deployed, and does not reference file, function, or anything like that. It also happens regardless of whether the package is in package.json, so not sure what you expect me to do here?

3) I thought I had made this clear- deploying a Nuxt project to a Google Cloud function. Without posting my entire source code I don't see what else I can do. 

Maybe if someone were able to point me in the right direction, it would be enough to help me resolve. 

Thanks

Comment: FYI you can edit the question to make changes instead of trying to cram everything into a comment.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.